# Cannot install visual studio 2015 - 1% is not a valid win32

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-10

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 pc but installer fails when it tries to install .NET 4.6.1 Developer pack
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This usually is a sign of a corrupted download (since the installer downloads components). Check your Internet connection and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that you get that error when trying to install VS 2015 on the Windows 10. That was the issue when something new tried to be installed on something like Windows XP. It definitely looks like an intermittent issue.

Please consider:

1) To install the VS using the different option (if you used web installer, try iso, and vice versa)

2) Check if you do not have any proxies, slow internet or whatever that may be the issue for the download

3) Install Developer Pack as a standalone package from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978), for example.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for the reply. Still no luck. 
 1. I have tried both web and standalone installer but I am getting same error. 
 2. I don't have any proxy setup. Also, I am getting 20.59Mbps for download and upload. I don't think it's a bad internet connection.
 3. I tried standalone .Net Dev pack installer and stopped working with the following error 
 
 "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Comment: @ApelMahmud can you see Event Viewer if there are any errors? The last one about "caused the program" may be there

Comment: I can't see any errors in the event log. Here is the installer log file https://app.box.com/s/ug3wckr7vcrb38hvut03x3kidbpgv8nz

Comment: Hm, i am almost out of options. Could you take a look at the that log C:\Users\amahmud\Downloads\log_000_netfxfullredistisv.txt.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post. Finally windows update fixed my problem.